# Composer Install throws error downloading Magento Package in Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

Trying to run composer install in a Magento 2.4.1 project is netting the following error:

`The "https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-page-builder/magento-module-page-builder-2.1.0.0.zip" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)`

All magento modules previous to this work, which means the Keys works. I have even created a different key to try and still same issue. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error, it's the credentials that don't have the necessary permissions

see this : https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud/issues/518

Answer (score 0):

For me this is a weird one, I have generated a new access key even tough the current one is working for other stuff. In case anyone stumble upon this try generating a new one it worked for me.